# How do I remove whitespace from stacked DIVs in IE?

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs stacked on top of eachother and enclosed by a third DIV. Then below the stacked DIVs I have a "red" DIV.

In Chrome, the DIVs show up correctly. In IE6 and IE7, there is a whitespace between the stacked DIVs and the red DIV.

[image]

```
<style>
div.imgbox {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:103px;
    height:58px;
}

div.imgthumb {
    position:relative;
    background:#000000;
    z-index:3;
    width:103px;
    height:58px;
}

div.imgplay {
    position:relative;
    top:-58;
    color:red;
    z-index:4;
}

div.imgplay a {
    width:103px;
    height:58px;
    display:block;
}

div.imgplay img {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
</style>

<div class="imgbox">
<div class="imgthumb"></div>
<div class="imgplay"><a href="#"><img src="http://freetvpower.com/attachments/Image/play_up.gif" /></a></div>
</div>
<div style="width:103px; height:58px; background-color:red;"></div>
```

Comment: witch version of ie did you test it on? I have ie9 and seems to work fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you have `top: -58` in your CSS, you've omitted the 'px' suffix - it should be:

```
div.imgplay {
    position:relative;
    top:-58px;
    color:red;
    z-index:4;
}
```

The following solution gets rid of the `position:relative` chaff, to get straight to the wheat:

http://jsfiddle.net/4UEdJ/
(untested in Internet Explorer :$)

Comment: Having `margin-top:-58px` might be a better way of doing this, by the way.

Comment: adding "px" didn't work and adding "margin-top" made the link imgplay inside disappear.

Comment: I don't have Internet Explorer handy, so I cannot test, but does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/4UEdJ/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You need 'position:relative;' in your last div and to change the position of the top, i.e.

```
<div style="width:103px; height:58px; top:-58px; background-color:red; position: relative;"></div>
```

Comment: Ah - but then it breaks it in Firefox ;)